# How to scale desktop icons in 18.04, v2.0, I want smaller!

Tags: gnome, icons

I was wondering how to do it smaller than 50%...
Checking the other 2 posts:

[How do I scale the enormously sized desktop icons on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030016/how-to-scale-the-enormously-sized-desktop-icons-in-gnome-3-28)

and

[How to scale desktop icons in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033010/how-to-scale-desktop-icons-in-18-04)

There we have a solution... The problem is that when scaling using the file manager `nautilus`, I can only go down to 50%. And that's still super big...

I remember from previous distros that I could go down to 33% (or even less if I remember correctly...).
I checked gnome-extensions but no luck there.

Thanks for your help!

Juancho!

Answer (score 2):

As the user CSManic explains in this [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374310), **Nautilus' minimum icon size is hardcoded**, so you'd need to download the source code, modify the file *nautilus-icon-info.h* and then (re)compile and (re)install the application.